# Set a DisplayTemplate to a WebGrid Column

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

i have this sample

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Expires, "DateTimeToDate" )
```

DateTimeToDate Display Template:

```
@model DateTime?
@Html.Label(Model.HasValue ? Model.Value.ToShortDateString(): string.Empty)
```

Column

```
... grid.Column("Expires", @Resources.Localization.Expires, canSort: true) ...
```

So, how i can use DisplayTemplate in webgrid column ?

regrads.

Answer (score 0):

If the `Expires` property of your view model is DateTime and you have a custom display template for it you may try the following:

```
grid.Column("Expires", format: @<text>@Html.DisplayFor(x => item)</text>)
```

This should render `~/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/DateTime.cshtml` for the Expires property of each item in the view model.

Comment: this dosent work, for some reason thsi display all values of model concatenated in the column

Comment: if i try to do `grid.Column(columnName: "Expires", header: @Resources.Localization.Expires, format: @<text>@Html.DisplayFor(x => item.Expires)</text>)`, i got this error _CS1963: An expression tree may not contain a dynamic operation_

Comment: @waldecir, try `@Html.DisplayFor(x => item)` as in my answer.

Comment: I have also tried this and it presents some strange results. Can you shed any more light on this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a snippet that worked for me, you will need to adjust it to your situation..

```
WebGridColumn adminColumn = grid.Column(columnName: string.Empty,
  header: string.Empty,
  format: (item) => new HtmlString(Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit",
    new { id = item.Id }, null).ToString() + "|" +
    Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.Id }, null).ToString()));
columns.Add(adminColumn);
```