# WebGrid format not outputting anything

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-4, webgrid

I have a table that I've built using a foreach loop in MVC 4 (Razor), and I'm trying to convert it to a WebGrid to take advantage of sorting.  Currently, I'm just trying to get the `format` parameter to work for me so that I can recreate the columns as I need them.  Here is a simple example that I can't get to work:

```
grid.Column(
    columnName: "ChangeId",
    format: (item) => @Html.DisplayFor(m => (item as ChangeStateViewModel).ChangeId)
)
```

This outputs nothing during rendering:

```
<td></td>
```

What am I doing wrong?  I've tried removing `(item) =>` and using `<text>...</text>`, but that doesn't display my value either.

**EDIT**

If I change it to the following, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5723256/128217), it *does* display all of the properties in the item; however, building from there just puts me right back where I was.

```
format: @<text>@Html.DisplayFor(x => item)</text>
```

**EDIT2**

```
format: @<text>@item.ChangeId</text>
```

works, of course, but doesn't give me the ability to provide a DisplayTemplate.

**EDIT3**

It looks like `(item as ChangeStateViewModel).ChangeId` is giving me `NULL`..  but why?  It's valued if I just use `@item.ChangeId`.

**EDIT4**

It looks like the default item provided (when you use `@<text>...</text>`) is a `System.Web.Helpers.WebGridRow`, which is why **EDIT3** provides the behavior that it does.  Something like the below will work, but only if you send it to a DisplayTemplate; for some reason, it won't show if you remove that `, "DisplayAny"` part.

```
format: @<text>@Html.DisplayFor(x => (item as WebGridRow)["ChangeId"], "DisplayAny")</text>
```

*That does make **EDIT2** rather confusing, though.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works, so I'm stopping here and marking this as an answer.  However, if there are better ways to approach this, I'd love to hear them.

```
format: @<text>@Html.DisplayFor(x => (item as WebGridRow)["ChangeId"], "DisplayAny")</text>
```

The DisplayTemplate is required; otherwise, this won't show.